# Which property group colour gives the best ROI , undeveloped or fully developed, in Monopoly?

Tags: monopoly

Everybody always goes for the dark blues in Monopoly (Mayfair and Park Lane in the UK edition), but I'm convinced that the cheaper colour groups offer a better return on investment, partly because you can fully develop them quicker, and partly because you can own more squares, thereby giving you more "hits" and a steadier income. But is there any analysis to support (or refute) this view?

Comment: btw - "fully developed" is not always the best. Most most properties, 3 houses is the point at which rent pays more than it cost to improve the property.

Answer (score 56):

My understanding is that the best three property groups are light blue (Angel Islington, Euston Road, Pentonville Road), orange (Bow Street, Marlborough Street, Vine Street), and dark blue (Park Lane, Mayfair). Light blue is good because the buildings are very cheap but give excellent returns. Orange is good because the likelihood of landing there is substantially higher, due to forced starting from Jail (gets you on a 6, 8 or 9). Finally, the dark blues are a good choice because *eventually* someone will draw the `Advance to Mayfair` card.

There is a much more [detailed analysis here](http://www.tkcs-collins.com/truman/monopoly/monopoly.shtml). The names are from the American set, but the calculations are the same.

Comment: Your source specifically mentions "The best return on investment to be found is from putting a third house on New York Avenue." (Most Expensive Orange) I would bet that Orange is therefor the best as a group for ROI.

Comment: Sweet. I remember reading a similar study on how Orange has the highest probability that someone will pay rent there and, for individual properties, I think it was Illinois.

Comment: Yes, and the main reason Illinois has the highest probability is because of the Chance card "Advance to Illinois".

Comment: anecdotally, the most frequent time to hit the Chance card "Go Back 3 Spaces" is the square just after Free Parking which takes you back to New York

Comment: @ghoppe The main reason Illinois is the most likely is because it's 14 squares after jail. The most likely die roll is 7, but that's only 1/6. However after 2 rolls, the most likely is 14. This is still only 11.3% (assuming only dice from jail) but it's higher than any other property. If you have reds, Illinois should always be the first to be developed.

Comment: @glowcoder The definition of "main reason" is debatable I guess. Remember that if a player throws doubles, that's going to reduce the odds of a 7 getting out of jail. There are 16 chance cards so the odds of getting "Advance to Illinois" is 1/16. We would have to calculate the odds of going to jail, moving out of jail with a total of 14 in the next two rolls and compare that to the odds of landing on Chance and drawing the Advance to Illinois card. Which one is the greater contributor? I suppose we can agree they both are factors.

Comment: @ghoppe I have to disagree on their magnitude: St. Chuck, Reading, and Boardwalk also have teleport cards, but they are not statistically the most likely to land on. Obviously something sets Illinois apart from them. GO in fact has two teleports, as it's in both card piles. And you don't need two 7's to get to Illinois from jail. As I stated, *any* two rolls from the jail space give you a 11.3% chance to land on Illinois.

Comment: continued... Having 3 chance spaces out of 40 on the board, and a 1/16 chance to draw that chance card, that tells me that each roll has a 3/(16*40) chance, or 0.46% chance, to teleport the player to Illinois. This means that for it to be a greater factor, you would have to start from Jail about 1/24 times. In other words, you'd start from jail about twice as often as the average square. Considering that it has two entry squares (itself and go to jail) PLUS two other methods of being sent there, it's obvious it carries that weight.

Answer (score 17):

There are two main features in the calculation. The first is to compare the sum of the (hotel) rents with the cost of building. Since the second "set" in each row charges higher rents without higher building costs, we will compare only the four second sets. The rents appear first, then the costs:

- Boardwalk Park Place (dark blue):  $3500 ÷ $2000 = 1.75
- Atlantic, Ventnor, Marvin (yellow): $3500 ÷ $2250 ≈ 1.56
- St. James, Tennesee, New York (orange): $2900 ÷ $1500 ≈ 1.93
- Oriental, Vermont, Connecticut (light blue): $1700 ÷ $750 ≈ 2.27

On this measures, the "light blues" are the most remunerative investment.

The other thing to note is that because of the "Go to Jail" square, one half of the board is much more "traveled" than the other. (Specifically the second and third rows.) This consideration seems to tip the balance in favor of the "orange" properties.

Comment: Every time I've played, I have gone for the light blues.

Comment: @drm65: Not a bad idea.

Answer (score -4):

The best Return on Investment for a color group tends to come from the red properties with at least 3 houses on each.

The thinking on this is fairly simple. The most likely roll of the dice is a seven. Which means that a player's rolls should average out to be a multiple of seven over time. Taking into account the monopoly board there are only 3 properties a person will land on if they rolled nothing but sevens all around the board. The first property is a purple which even built up doesn't make you much, the second property is the first red property which costs a bit to build up but is well worth the investment and the third is a green property which cost way to much to build all the way up.

The relative investment required to build up the red properties is fairly cheap and as you are building on them people tend to land on these a lot especially if they are just getting out of jail since a multiple of 2 sevens takes them straight from jail to the most expensive of these properties.

As Reds are the only color group that are in the way of the average roll of the dice, both from go and jail, they represent the highest grossing properties in the entire game.

Comment: Do you have any quantitative analysis to back up this answer?

Comment: Going from "the average roll tends to 7 over time" to "the average distribution of landings matches what would happen if you rolled 7 each time" is completely wrong.

Answer (score -4):

Personally i love ALL SETS. The Blue light is cheap and easier tradeable. Is so fast that when you collect all with 750 extra dollas you gain 600 dollars. Is no K.O but slow much the opponent.

The orange is the best from my. With extra 900 dollars (after the set complete) is the some from light blue, and later you can raised to 1000. In fact the jail bonus is great. The only negative of the set ? Much harder to collect the full set.

the first set is fine from me. Cannot win alone, but if you get both is a nice money bonus i mean only i hit you taken your money back. (total cost only 620)

THe 2nd best from my is the last one. In fact is only 2 cards and if you are lucky and collect both with total cost of 1750 can ONKO opponent. In fact is the only set that is dander with 2 house.(light blue rage) With 3 is on orange rage

From yellow or red i love both but slighly more official i thing is the red one. Is more change to hit from jail.

Clearly the worst from me is the Green one. Too expensive, too slow. 900 dollars from buying (no one collect the green) and other 1800 from hitting the orange rake? i mean 1000 is Allready huge damage.

Train is VERY GOOD cards from me. Is cheap (200 each and in practise 100 if you sell it). With 3+ copy is a good money bonus. i can easy pass the other 2 cards.(propable and the green one).

I have small experience from a computers game from 4 total players

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, which explicitly states need for analysis, not opinions or limited personal experience.